# Showing irreducibility of a polynomial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

How would you go about showing that $p(x)=\frac{x^5-1}{x-1}=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. I'm having trouble seeing how one can show whether this kind of polynomials are irreducible or not

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Surely a duplicate.

Comment: Try showing  $p(x+1)$ is irreducible using Eisenstein's criterion. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Calculate $p(x+1)$ and note that $p(x)$ is irreducible iff
$p(x+1)$ is

You may be interested in further reading about [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial)